# SQL select include subquery that contain a where IN() error

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I want to select data in MySQL with subquery that contain WHERE IN query

```
SELECT id_sip, nip_baru, id_finger, nama_pegawai, gelar_depan,
gelar_belakang, kelamin, nama_kelamin,  nama_status, id_golongan,
kode_golongan, tmt_jabatan_utama, 
CONCAT(kode_golongan, ' - ', nama_golongan) 
AS golongan, id_pendidikan,  kode_pendidikan, nama_status_ju, nama_nama_ju, 
DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), tmt_cpns) AS masa_kerja ,

(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(jurusan_pendidikan SEPARATOR ', ')
FROM tbl_riwayat_pendidikan 
LEFT JOIN tbl_master_pegawai 
USING(id_sip)
WHERE id_sip IN(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8) 
GROUP BY id_sip) AS id_prodi 
FROM tbl_master_pegawai 
LEFT JOIN tbl_data_kelamin 
ON tbl_data_kelamin.`id_kelamin` = tbl_master_pegawai.`kelamin`
LEFT JOIN tbl_data_status 
ON tbl_data_status.`id_status` = tbl_master_pegawai.`status_pegawai`
LEFT JOIN tbl_data_golongan 
ON tbl_data_golongan.`id_golongan` = tbl_master_pegawai.`golongan_pegawai`  
LEFT JOIN tbl_data_pendidikan 
ON tbl_data_pendidikan.`id_pendidikan` = tbl_master_pegawai.`pendidikan`  
LEFT JOIN tbl_data_jabatanutama_status 
ON tbl_data_jabatanutama_status.`id_status_ju` = tbl_master_pegawai.`jabatan_utama`
LEFT JOIN tbl_data_jabatanutama_nama
ON tbl_data_jabatanutama_nama.`no_nama_ju` = tbl_master_pegawai.`nama_jabatan_utama`
WHERE id_sip IN(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)
```

I want the results to follow the rows of each WHERE query.
but the query above show error "Subquery returns more than 1 row"

```
(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(jurusan_pendidikan SEPARATOR ', ') 
FROM tbl_riwayat_pendidikan 
LEFT JOIN tbl_master_pegawai 
USING(id_sip)
WHERE id_sip IN(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8) 
GROUP BY id_sip) AS id_prodi
```

or

```
(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(jurusan_pendidikan SEPARATOR ', ') 
FROM tbl_riwayat_pendidikan 
LEFT JOIN tbl_master_pegawai 
USING(id_sip)
WHERE id_sip = id_sip 
GROUP BY id_sip) AS id_prodi
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

```
SELECT id_sip as id, nip_baru, id_finger, nama_pegawai, gelar_depan,
gelar_belakang, kelamin, nama_kelamin,  nama_status, id_golongan,
kode_golongan, tmt_jabatan_utama, 
CONCAT(kode_golongan, ' - ', nama_golongan) 
AS golongan, id_pendidikan,  kode_pendidikan, nama_status_ju, nama_nama_ju, 
DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), tmt_cpns) AS masa_kerja ,

(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(jurusan_pendidikan SEPARATOR ', ')
FROM tbl_riwayat_pendidikan 
LEFT JOIN tbl_master_pegawai 
USING(id_sip)
WHERE id_sip = id 
GROUP BY id_sip) AS id_prodi
```

sorry for my first question at stackoverflow